# Tailwind css not working on route likes /api/user/forget/123/asddd

Tags: tailwind-css, dynamic-routing

i have configure tailwind css and its working fine but when i give routes like api/user/forget/id/token then tailwind css not working on that route

my configuration

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

how to get working tailwind classes on that type of route

Comment: Are your api route files inside the `src` folder?

Comment: yes inside src folder

Comment: Are you using a framework? It may be related to that. Also, does the output have no Tailwind css at all, or does it have some Tailwind css but not for the classes included on that route?